# Data truncation warning without width change

Tags: mariadb, sql-null

I have a `BINARY(2) DEFAULT NULL` column in a MariaDB InnoDB table to store country code, but I would like to remove nullability (the value is always set), so I am trying to run the following query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY COLUMN `country_code` BINARY(2) NOT NULL;
```

However, I have the following error:

```
Error 1265: Data truncated for column 'country_code' at row 357
```

There are no rows with values that exceed 2 characters, checked with

```sql
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`country_code`)) FROM `table_name`
```

Which returns 2.

In that case, what is the possible cause of data truncation, and how to workaround?

Comment: Strange.  Any clue what is on and around row 35?   Do `SELECT HEX(country_code) ...` if practical.

Comment: No, nothing special, `HEX(country_code)` shows 2 bytes for everything. In fact, row 357 has the same value as row 356 (and several others before).